# Letter Frequency

Tags: java, frequency-analysis

I have a assignment in which the user needs to enter a string, my program so far prints out the number of times it occurs, but I also need to show the frequency of the letter so for example if i would enter "ab" - It would show
Letter Occurs Frequency
  a      1       0.5
  b      1       0.5

Any Help would be deeply appreciated

Thanks In advance

```
import java.io.*;

public class ProgrammingAsignment {

public static void main (String [] args)throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter Any Text:");
    String output = BR.readLine();
    output=output.toLowerCase();
    int length = output.length();
    char character;

    System.out.println("Letters\tFrequency\tCount");

    int count = 0;
    for(char i ='a'; i<='z'; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<length; j++)
        {
            character = output.charAt(j);
            if(character==i)
                count++;
        }
        if(count!=0)
        {
            System.out.println(i+"\t\t"+count);
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that use a map to store the encountered letters and keeps an up to date count for each letter encountered.   A map allows you to not know in advance how many different characters you will encounter in the output.

```
package lettercount;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

//Version that demonstrates using a map to keep a running count for items encountered
//This way you only have to step through the input once.
public class ProgrammingAssignment {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter Any Text: ");
    String output = BR.readLine();
    output=output.toLowerCase();

    int length = output.length();
    char character;
    int totalCount = 0;

    //we'll store each encountered character in this map, along with a count of the number
    //of times encountered.
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

    //Loop over the output once, character by character
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        character = output.charAt(i);
        totalCount++; //This is the total number of characters we've found in the output

        Integer countForCharacter = 0;
        //check in map if we have a count for this character
        if (map.containsKey(character)) {
            //get the current count we have for this character
            countForCharacter = map.get(character);
            //increment
            countForCharacter++;
            //increment the count
        } else {
            countForCharacter = 1;
        }

        //Now put the up to date count into the map
        map.put(character, countForCharacter);
    }


    //Get the found characters as an array of Character
    Character[] charactersFound = map.keySet().toArray(new Character[0]);

    System.out.println("Letters\tFrequency\tCount");
    for(int k = 0; k < charactersFound.length; k++)
    {
        character = charactersFound[k];
        System.out.println(character+
                "\t" +
                //Following line gets the count for the character and divides by totalCount,
                //making sure that the the result is a floating point
                (map.get(character)/((float)totalCount)) +
                "\t"+
                //get the count for the character
                map.get(character));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thats is absolutely perfect,thank you very much you have saved me lot of time and know I can relax slightly again Thank you soo mucj

Answer (score 1):

Your code right now prints out the Occurs. So to do the Frequency, add a new variable in your outer `for` loop, something like `sum_count`. At the end of every inner `for` loop iteration, add the value of count to `sum_count`, like so:

```
int sum_count = 0;
for(char i ='a'; i<='z'; i++)
{
        int count = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<length; j++)
        {
            character = output.charAt(j);
            if(character==i)
                count++;
        }
        sum_count += count; 
      ...
 }
```

Now, for each letter, just your value for Occurs, which is `count`, and divide it by `sum_count`.

```
System.out.println(i+"\t\t"+count+"\t\t"+sum_count/count);
```

Comment: I have tried that code when I run the program it shows

letters frequency count
  a            1             1
   b          1               2

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at ProgrammingAssignment1.main(ProgrammingAssignment1.java:29)

Comment: Also If i put in anything else from ab it only shows A with errors

Answer (score 0):

Save in an array the count for every letter. To obtain the frequency of any letter, divide its count by the sum of the counts of all the letters.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that, i am particularly new to java, could you show me some sample code

Comment: Look at Davide Lorenzo MARINO 's answer. It contains some lines of code you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is build an int array of size 26 (the number of chars from a to z) or 52 (if you need to differentiate between upper and lower case) or 128 (if you need to map all ascii chars).
For example:

```
int[] counter = new int[128];
```

After loop between your chars and add 1 to each element.
For example if you find the A letter you have to do that:

```
counter[(int) 'A']++;
```

Or more general if ch is the current char:

```
counter[(int) ch]++;
```

At the end you will have all the data that you need to calculate frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

I would use RegEx

```
   public CountFrequency wordString(String word, String input){
        String regex = "\\b" + word;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input); 
        int count = 0;

        while(m.find()){
         count++;
        }

        if(count =< 0){
            return new CountFrequency(0, 0.0);          
        }
        return new CountFrequency(count, (double)input.size()/count);       
   }




class CountFrequency{
        private int count = 0;
        private double frequency = 0.0;

        public CountFrequency(int count, double frequency){
            this.count = count;
            this.frequency = frequency;
        }

        int getCount(){
            return count;
        }

        double getFrequency(){
            return frequency;
        }
   }
```

Comment: If you are just looking for the whole word use regex = "\\b" + word + "\\b";